# Неправильная кодировка во view-source

Tags: html, postgresql, asp.net-core, utf-8, кодировка

Всем привет! Когда в браузере нажимаю F12, в *коде элемента* кириллические символы отображаются нормально:

```
<title>Инвестирование в автомобили под аренду</title>
<meta name="Description" content="Цель инвестирования : приобретение автомобилей среднего класса с двигателем объемом не более 2-х литров для дальнейшего предоставления аренды под такси. Существует высокий спрос на аренду автомобилей в связи с увеличением объема пассажирских перевозо">
```

А если я нажму Ctrl+U (view-source), то этот же участок кода в браузере оторажается в таком виде:

```
<title>&#x418;&#x43D;&#x432;&#x435;&#x441;&#x442;&#x438;&#x440;&#x43E;&#x432;&#x430;&#x43D;&#x438;&#x435; &#x432; &#x430;&#x432;&#x442;&#x43E;&#x43C;&#x43E;&#x431;&#x438;&#x43B;&#x438; &#x43F;&#x43E;&#x434; &#x430;&#x440;&#x435;&#x43D;&#x434;&#x443;</title>
<meta name="Description" content="&#x426;&#x435;&#x43B;&#x44C; &#x438;&#x43D;&#x432;&#x435;&#x441;&#x442;&#x438;&#x440;&#x43E;&#x432;&#x430;&#x43D;&#x438;&#x44F; : &#x43F;&#x440;&#x438;&#x43E;&#x431;&#x440;&#x435;&#x442;&#x435;&#x43D;&#x438;&#x435; &#x430;&#x432;&#x442;&#x43E;&#x43C;&#x43E;&#x431;&#x438;&#x43B;&#x435;&#x439; &#x441;&#x440;&#x435;&#x434;&#x43D;&#x435;&#x433;&#x43E; &#x43A;&#x43B;&#x430;&#x441;&#x441;" />`
```

(сократил для наглядности)

Эта проблема встречается только с текстом, который получается из базы данных. 
База данных: Postgres, кодировка: UTF-8.
Сервер: ASP.NET Core.
Тестил на разных браузерах.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему так происходит и как это исправить.

Comment: `&#x418;` - допустимая форма записи UTF8 символа в HTML. Ищите где и зачем это так преобразовывает ваше приложение.

Comment: @Мелкий, да, я понимаю, что это допустимая форма UTF8, но почему браузер в инструментах разработчика (F12) выводит нормально, а в view-source(ctrl+u) не так

Comment: Потому что в view-source то что получил в ответ на запрос без дальнейших преобразований, а в инструментах разработчика собственное представление текущего состояния документа (которое может например активно меняться через js и уже сильно отличаться от того что ответил на запрос сервер)

Comment: @Мелкий спасибо, ваш комментарий помог найти проблему. Написал ответ к своему вопросу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в Razor. Добавил эту строчку в ConfigureServices и все заработало:

`services.AddWebEncoders(o => { o.TextEncoderSettings = new System.Text.Encodings.Web.TextEncoderSettings(UnicodeRanges.All); });`

Answer (score 1):

Происходит так потому, что с сервера приходит `&#x418;`.

Браузер парсит HTML и строит DOM -- превращает `&#x418;` в `И` -- это нормально.